# UIautomatorviewer cannot create UI xml hierarchy for default calling app in samsung S6 on android 7

Tags: python-appium, uiautomatorviewer

I need xpath of dial button,answer button, reject call button and so on but UIautomatorviewer doesnt create UI xml hierarchy for default calling app in samsung S6. Is there any other way to get these UI elements? Uiautomatorviewer works fine on HTC 10 with android 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Appium-Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop):

Just launch your application under test with appium-desktop, then switch on device/emulator to any app you want (e.g. Dialer app) and refresh inspector:
[image]